# how to accept a value from an user in an android application developing eclipse?

Tags: android, button

When user interacts with the android app, how to store the value the user inputs, before the button is pressed?
This is the code we have written. Please tell us how to correct it:

```
public class configroom extends Activity {

    public String nroom;

    @override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_config_room);

      Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbtn1);

      nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

          @override

          public void onClick (View v) {

               getnumrooms(nroom);

               Intent i = new Intent (ConfigRoom.this, ConfigRoom2.class);

               i.putExtra("NumOfRooms",nroom);

               startActivityForResult(i,0);

          }
     });
    }

      void getnumrooms(String nroom) {

            EditText numberDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numrm1);
            nroom = (numberDisplay.getText().toString());

      }

      @override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_config_room1,menu);
            return true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Here are your storage options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: call your function "getnumrooms(nroom);" after lost focus of EditText Component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you meant by "before button is pressed" but you can use TextChangedListener.

It would look like this more or less:

```
EditText numberDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numrm1);
numberDisplay.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           nroom = (s.getText().toString());
     }
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

apply focuschange listner on your edittext

```
txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus)
           //do job here owhen Edittext lose focus 
    }
});
```

hopefully it will serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

Use **sharedprefernces** in android

```
public class configroom extends Activity {

public String nroom;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_config_room);

  Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbtn1);
  getnumrooms();
  nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

      @override

      public void onClick (View v) {

           String nroom=sharedpreferences.getString("room",""); 

           Intent i = new Intent (ConfigRoom.this, ConfigRoom2.class);

           i.putExtra("NumOfRooms",nroom);

           startActivityForResult(i,0);

      }
 });
}

  void getnumrooms() {

        EditText numberDisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numrm1);
        nroom = (numberDisplay.getText().toString());
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
   editor.putString("room", nroom);
   editor.commit();

  }

  @override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_config_room1,menu);
        return true;
  }
```

}